# Is "I'm so happy because I was born in Juni 30" correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, phrase-usage

I want to create a custom tshirt design with one of this sentences :

> I'm happy today because I was born in Juni 30
>
> I'm so happy because I was born in Juni 30

**[The Situation]**
I want him to wear the shirt on his birthday. But on the other hand, I also want him to keep wearing his shirts on other days. Therefore, I didn't make a sentence like "I am happy today because it is Juni 30" that looks not suitable for wear at other days.

Are these two sentences correct? or do you have any other sentence suggestions for the situation?

Comment: Did you mean June or July?

Comment: @SovereignSun   It's June (in German I suppose).

Comment: The second one, because you are not restricting "happy" (happiness) to today or any particular day. Also, we would say *on* June 30" or "*on* June 30th", with June in English since you are writing that way after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your example:

1. The 6th month of the year is called *June*, not *Juni*.
2. We say we are born *on* a certain date, not *in* it.
3. In a displayed message like this, we usually want the words to be as big as possible, so we use as few words as possible to express a message. On a tee-shirt it's obvious the phrase refers to the person wearing the shirt, so we can eliminate the subject.  For example, a shirt might just say something like

> Happy to be born June 30

Answer (score 0):

It's rather odd to wear such a shirt, I know I wouldn't, but there can be many ways to phrase your idea, the sentence in the title does make sense, you can keep it.

One way to do it is to make up a slogan.